# Edit mode cursor is too small too see

Tags: edit-mode, mouse

Just updated to 2.83. Before this I know that there was an option in the interface to tab of the preferences to enlarge the edit mode cursor. Now I can't find it and am losing sight of the cursor every time I tab to edit mode.

Did the developers move the option or was it removed. Is there any other options to improve the cursor visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They removed it for 2.83. Users were complaining that it didn't scale well, and I don't think it worked on mac at all (the checkbox was there, but the cursors did not obey).

What they opted to do was remove, and relegate control of all the cursors back to the OS.

In windows 10 you adjust it like this (for some reason the cursor does not appear on screenshots - you'll just have to take my word for it):

[image: Cursor size]

Comment: Thanks for clearing up the issue. Sad that it was reallty gone.